# SQL Server how to set a default value when the column is null

Tags: sql-server

This is my sql in SQL server:

```
SELECT user_Name ,user_pass ,user_hometown FROM user_baseinfo
```

Sometimes the column can be null. When it is, I want to replace it with a default value.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use case

```
select case 
          when user_Name is null then "default value" 
          else user_name 
       end  
from table
```

Comment: Can shorter: isnull(val1, val2) and this way it will respect column specification, so insert from that select will not fail cause of too long replacement.

Answer (score 29):

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(user_Name, 'Unknown Name') AS user_Name,
    ISNULL(user_pass, 'Unknown Pass') AS user_pass,
    ISNULL(user_hometown, 'Unknown Hometown') AS user_hometown
FROM user_baseinfo
```

---

Be aware though that `ISNULL` has precedence of the first argument type. This may cause undesired cutting of the default value, if column in the first argument has type, which is shorter than that of the default value. In such cases `COALESCE` is the better choice.

Below is an example showing the difference between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (Value1 varchar(100), Value2 char(3));

INSERT INTO #Sample (Value1, Value2)
VALUES
    ('AAA', 'AAA'),
    ('BBB', 'BBB'),
    ('CCC', 'CCC'),
    (NULL, NULL);

SELECT
    ISNULL(Value1, 'Default') AS Value1,
    ISNULL(Value2, 'Default') AS Value2
FROM #Sample;

SELECT
    COALESCE(Value1, 'Default') AS Value1,
    COALESCE(Value2, 'Default') AS Value2
FROM #Sample;
```

See that `Default` cuts down to `Def` when `ISNULL` is used.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `DEFAULT` keyword.

**Example taken from website**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'
)
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp) is a link to the site.

Comment: There are also times when the structure of the DB cannot be changed, and the default value is only needed in one query, this answer is not good for generic cases.

Comment: For MS SQL, default values must be not null otherwise MS SQL will not insert a default value.

Answer (score 3):

For existing rows (Assuming column is `varchar`)

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD CONSTRAINT ConstraintName DEFAULT N'Default Value' FOR ColumnName;
```