# How to default a null value?

Tags: sql-server

I am student learning SQL Server 2012. I have data on server which has `NULL` and different values in the column. I am trying to write a query that show `1` for `NULL` row  and `0` for row that has values on it. Can anyone tell me how to write that.

Comment: Use either [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) or [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server how to set a default value when the column is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718643/sql-server-how-to-set-a-default-value-when-the-column-is-null)

Comment: @ManoDestra could you please demonstrate how to use ISNULL to solve this ? I tried this myself, but it looks a bit long and slow: SELECT ISNULL(REPLACE(col,col, 0),1). If the column is numeric it is a easier with SELECT ISNULL(col-col,1). I still prefer using CASE or IIF

Comment: Isnull would be good if you just wanted to replace the NULL with something else, not if you want to replace the actual value with a 1 too. Case statements are your friend in this instance.

Comment: Thank You so much for helping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select case when mycolumn is null then 1 else 0 end
from mytable
```

Comment: @rasheedshahzad no problem, please mark my answer as accepted, or at least as useful, if it has helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really basic question, what research have you done before asking here? If you show what you've tried and what you're stuck on you will get much better answers.

In this instance you want a case statement to meet this requirement;

```
SELECT
CASE 
    WHEN FieldName IS NULL 
        THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END 
FROM TableName
```

Be sure to read up on three valued logic and never use 'FieldName = NULL'

Comment: Sure, no worries. If this solves the issue then please feel free to mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use also iif:

```
select iif(FieldName is null, 1, 0) as FieldName from TableName
```

Comment: no it is not. It is similar to ternary operator in certain program languages: val == true ? true_statement : false_statement;

Comment: @sagi it is IIF in sqlserver 2012

Comment: My fault, though this is MySQL .