# How to handle NULL's to show 0 in T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I change the SQL statement below to show 0 instead of Null when Null is the result?

```
SELECT cast (sum([ColumnA]) as DECIMAL(18,0)) AS [Weight] 
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Tabel1]
```

Comment: Use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server how to set a default value when the column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718643/sql-server-how-to-set-a-default-value-when-the-column-is-null)

Comment: I've tried but I don't know where to place the COALESCE function to get it working

Comment: What did you try?   The documentation on the COALESCE function is pretty clear.

Comment: SELECT cast (sum, COALESCE([ColumnA],0) as DECIMAL(18,0)) AS [Weight] 
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Tabel1]

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Don't use coalesce here, use isnull `SELECT cast (sum(isnull([ColumnA],0)) as DECIMAL(18,0)) AS [Weight] 
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Tabel1]`. And your attempt was missing parentheses in the proper place.

Comment: Thanks scsimon but that still returns null rather than 0

Comment: @scsimon, why do you advise to use `isnull` rather than `coalesce`?

Comment: Cause it's pointless and this is the perfect use for ISNULL

Comment: @Scsimon both functions still return NULL?

Comment: @scsimon... ? I don't understand what you mean with your 'pointless' remark. `Coalesce` fits this use just as good, and it's ANSI SQL.

Comment: This seems like a good place to insert this link. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT cast(COALESCE(sum([ColumnA]), 0) as DECIMAL(18,0)) AS [Weight] 
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Tabel1]
```